# Best method to make an online database searchable?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm doing some statistical stuff for a university and I've got a question.  I've got a starter background in C++ and read up on some C# and since I have access to the entire MS suite I think I'll go ahead and use the .NET framework.  My question is, I would like to make my database searchable online.  I'll fancy it up with some jQuery but for the most part, all I'll need is permissions to view or write and all of the queries one might like to run.  My question: is there a specific method that would be more expedient for developing this?  The MVC framework or something else?

Comment: What database are you planning to use? Your question is more related to that choice than any other programming language or framework (e.g. MVC).

Comment: Is search going to happen through a web UI or through an API/webservices?

Comment: web UI.  i think that will provide the best experience and more WOW factor for users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server, I think LinqToSQL provides the quickest, most convenient direct access to your data from C#.  Start with a Linq data context, and then you can manipulate records in your database via strongly typed C# objects.

Comment: what the reading that i've done i was going to guess linqtoSQL.  is this are variables simply represented by sql queries?

Comment: Classes are generated for each table in your context.  Each class corresponds to a table, and has properties typed appropriately for the corresponding field in the database.